# Travelling To The US under the Muslim ban

Tags: visas, usa

About the Muslim ban (executive order 13769) I've searched about it and what I could understand is that people from Iran, Libya, North Korea, Somali, Syria, Yemen and Venezuela are banned from entering the US or getting a US Visa.

My question is until when will the people from these countries will stay banned, and can those people now in May 2019, get a Visa for the US or enter it normally?

Comment: Unfortunately nobody can read Trumps mind.

Comment: Wikipedia says executive order 13769 has been replaced by [Executive Order 13780](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executive_Order_13780) from March 6, 2017. The new order is still in force and is in essence similar to the order you have quoted. The wiki article also has a section on current status by nationality. As written your question is hard to answer (we cannot predict when POTUS will change his policy) and _may_ be too broad (you may want to focus on a particular nationality).

Comment: Note that the rules are actually a lot more specific that a blanket ban on all citizens from those countries, and vary from country to country, with different types of visas still allowed for some countries.

Comment: Thanks guys for your great answers, So nobody from the countries above can get a Visa for US if he/she dont have exceptions?!

Comment: It's not a muslim ban. Christians, Hindus etc. from these countries are also banned, and Muslims from other countries are fine. Well, mostly fine. Now whether Donald Trump understands finer details like this I don't know.

Answer (score 9):

On January 20, 2021, President Biden repealed Trump's executive order and instructed embassies to start processing visa applications for the affected countries again: https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/presidential-actions/2021/01/20/proclamation-ending-discriminatory-bans-on-entry-to-the-united-states/

Entering the US remains difficult due to COVID travel bans and embassy closures, but at least this particular obstacle is now history.